# Use Firebase auth phone(OTP) on devices that has no google play services and Chrome

Tags: android, firebase-authentication, phone-number

my app runs on custom devices that have no Google Play services and Google Chrome, and I use Firebase phone Auth to authenticate my users, but when trying to send OTP from a device that has no GS and Chrome the app crashes, I wonder if there is a way to skip/disable the checking process that Google does as explained [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth#enable-app-verification) so I can verify the phone number on these devices smoothly.